# Override IBOutlet properties from super class?

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

I would like to create a super class in a framework that modifies IBOutlet properties. However, I would like a subclass to be connected to the storyboard, since I don't want to connect the controls to the class in the framework.

For example, the super class in my framework looks like this:

```
public class MySuperDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet public weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet public weak var dateLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet public weak var contentWebView: UIWebView?

    ...
}
```

Then in the subclass, I would like to control-drag controls onto the subclass. So I have to expose those properties by overriding. I'm trying to do this but it won't allow me:

```
class MyDetailViewController: MySuperDetailViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var contentWebView: UIWebView?

}
```

The error I get is: `Cannot override with a stored property 'titleLabel', 'dateLabel', and 'contentWebView'`.

How can I do this or better approach to this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't try to recreate the variables in the subclass; the `IBOutlet` variables still exist. You can still connect them inside of Interface Builder in a number of ways.

1. Utilites (right panel) -> Connection Inspector - drag from the list of IBOutlets.
2. Document Outline (left panel) - drag from `MyDetailViewController`
3. Drag from the yellow circle when you have the UIViewController selected in Interface Builder

Note: All `UIViewController` subclasses inherit an IBOutlet named `view`; this property already exists in Interface Builder even though you can't click + drag to connect it.

Answer (score 0):

All `sub-classes` get direct access to the `outlets` in the `super-class`. So you can just change the `properties` of the `outlets` direcly in the respective `sub-class`. Like this:

```
class MySubClass: MySuperClass {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mySuperClassOutlet.text = "This overrides superclass text"
    }
}
```